# Should external resource lists be allowed on the site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was looking at the question [Guitar fretboard diagram generators](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/guitar-fretboard-diagram-generators)

Providing a list of ways that are often used to diagram fretboards is fine, but when It's specifically asking "Are there any recommended websites, and/or software" then to me that's a red flag for a close vote.

So, are questions like this one ok? it seems it should have been re-worded to ask for diagram types so the user can go and search themselves, rather than directing to a specific product.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a red flag. This particular question has come up with some more or less decent answers, but if you see down the list, the answers are not very good fit. This indicates that there are problems with this type of questions.

The reason it is not closed, is that it is not very clear that it is a shopping question. The long list of opinion based answers is indicator that it should have been closed or re-worded in the beginning. It is a bit late to do much with the question itself now, as the top answer give some value to our site.